# What is the best way to approach chaining callbacks in javascript / typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I want to have a single endpoint that does this:

- Create House and store in the database.
- When we know it has been stored in the database, we create pricing for it, saved to the database as well.
- Then query the Pricing Table using "type_of_room", get the average of price, and use the price to calculate the new proposed price.

Problem : I am passing the data here but it is not working when i console log it outside the callback : `avgPricePerSquareMetre = data[0].getDataValue("price");`

Problem 2: Even if the problem one is solved, I do not know how to save the Pricing yet again since I only want to pass the new proposed price to the Pricing table.

What is the best practice on how to handle this, please? Any suggestions? 
I believe I am missing something here but I do not know what it is.

```
router.post("/register", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  let propertyData: object;
  let test: any;
  let avgPricePerSquareMetre: number; 

  const property = new House({
    ... // some req body data. 
  });
  property
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      propertyData = data;
      if (!data) {
        return res.status(422).json(`Infomation could not be processed.`);
      }
      const pricing = new Pricing({
        ... // some req body data.
      });
      pricing.save().then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
          return res.status(422).json(`Infomation could not be processed.`);
        }

        Pricing.findAll({
          attributes: [
            "type_of_room",
            [
              Sequelize.fn("AVG", Sequelize.col("price")),
              "price",
            ],
          ],
          group: "type_of_room",
          order: [
            [Sequelize.fn("AVG", Sequelize.col("price")), "DESC"],
          ],
        }).then((data) => {
          if (data) {
            // Data passed : Confirmed working until here. 
            avgPricePerSquareMetre = data[0].getDataValue("price"); 

          }
        });

        console.log("avgPricePerSquareMetre - 1", avgPricePerSquareMetre);
        // --> THIS ISSUE :  this data is not being passed to avgPricePerSquareMetre
      });
      return res.status(201).json({
        created: true,
        avg_price_per_square_metre: avgPricePerSquareMetre,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: error,
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Inside a `.then()`, return any additional promises you make in order to chain them together.  So, for example, change `Pricing.findAll({...})` to `return Pricing.findAll({...})`.  This will "chain" the promises together so they are all linked/sequenced together.  This will also propagate any errors in the new promise back up to the parent.

Comment: `avgPricePerSquareMetre` is actually set, but after you have `console.log` it. Any particular reason you want to do `console.log` and `res.json()` outside the callback? you can just move it there

Comment: I prefer to use async/await.

Comment: @thammada console log because I wanted to see the value assigned to be sure my calculation was right

Comment: @Dami I mean why not just do it in the callback where you have access to the data? You can just do `res.status(201).json()` in `Pricing.findAll().then` callback

Comment: What’s `router`? Express?

Comment: I'd not use then statements. I'd use async await Patten with closures.

Comment: @Ry- it is express using typescript

Comment: Promise chaining is based on `return`